# Configuring SSH Agent Plugin for Jenkins on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I am trying to configure the SSH Agent Plugin (v1.15) on a Windows installation of Jenkins (v2.103) to be able to issue commands via ssh to a remote machine.

I have installed the plugin and I have added an entry into Jenkins Credentials (shown below) which contains the private key and passphrase which can login to the remote machine (hostname: corp-wfdemo).  I have confirmed this key works for authenticating the user running Jenkins.

[image: Credentials in Jenkins]

I've created a Pipeline project and added this Groovy script to test out ssh:

```
node ('ssh') {
    stage ('test') {
        sshagent(['corp-wfdemo']) {
            sh 'ls -la'
        }
    }
}
```

The Jenkins master has the label `ssh`. This is a Windows Server 2012 machine with Git Bash (MINGW64) installed.

When I try running this job it fails when trying to find some auto-generated askpass.sh script.  Here's the output:

[image: Jenkins job output]

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

Also, each time I try running this job a new instance of `ssh-agent` is spawned and not terminated, leaving this mess:

[image: ssh-agent processes]

Comment: 1) Try once running the commands manually from the command prompt once to clear there is error from the authentication point.
2) While execution the ssh-ask command it was execution from windows folder where the temp path is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Git for Windows for a long time now, and I struggled with fundamentally the same issue. When working with github or other remote ssh repos, I wanted to be able to open multiple windows but have them all share the same ssh agent.

Below is the full content of what I call my `assure_ssh_agent` shell function for Git Bash. Source its definition in every independent session that you run.  I have the following two lines in my `~/.profile`.

```
. ~/ssh-agent.sh
assure_ssh_agent
```

After the function has been defined you can ssh-add your keyfiles or, if you define a list of them in `.ssh/keylist`, you can just run `addkeys`, which will load all of them into the agent for 10 hours by default, which should be enough for a normal working day and long lunchbreak.

How it works: The script maintains shared state in the file `.ssh/pid_store`.
If `assure_ssh_agent()` cannot find a valid pid it will start a new agent, and write its pid and socket there, for any subsequent session.

---

Contents of `ssh-agent.sh`:

```sh
# echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AGENT_PID

is_running() {
  (kill -0 ${1:?PID}) 2> /dev/null
}

agent_pid_store() {
  (
  pid_store=$HOME/.ssh/agent_pid
  touch -a $pid_store
  case $1 in
  ( read ) read pid sock < $pid_store && echo $pid $sock
      [ -n "$sock" ]
  ;;
  ( write) echo \
            ${SSH_AGENT_PID:?} \
            ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK:?} > $pid_store
  ;;
  ( clear ) rm -f ${pid_store:?}
  esac
  )
}

find_active_ssh_agent() {
  (
  set -- $(agent_pid_store read)
  pid=$1 sock=$2
  case $1 in
  ("") return 1
  ;;
  ($SSH_AGENT_PID)
     is_running $SSH_AGENT_PID && echo $SSH_AGENT_PID $2
  ;;
  (*)
     is_running $pid && echo $pid $sock && return
     return 1
  ;;
  esac
  )
}

ssh_agent_is_running() {
  (find_active_ssh_agent | read _was_there_something_to_read_)
}


assure_ssh_agent() {
  unset GIT_SSH
  unset SVN_SSH

  set -- $(
    find_active_ssh_agent
  ) && pid=$1 sock=$2

  :  "pid='$pid' sock='$sock'"
  :  "length: pid:${#pid} sock:${#sock}"

  case $pid$sock in
  ( "" )
    printf  "* " >& 2 
    eval $( ssh-agent ) > /dev/null
    agent_pid_store write
    echo "ssh agent ${SSH_AGENT_PID}" >& 2 
    return
  ;;
  ( * )
    export SSH_AGENT_PID=$pid SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$sock
    echo "ssh agent ${SSH_AGENT_PID}" >& 2 
    set +x
    return
  ;;
  esac
}

addkeys(){
  (set -e #-x
  unset GIT_SSH
  unset SVN_SSH
  Keyfile_Timeout=36000

  cd ~/.ssh 
  exec < keylist || 
    exit 1 $(echo >& 2 "Add names of keyfiles to $HOME/.ssh/keylist")
  while read keyfile
  do
    ssh-add -t ${Keyfile_Timeout} ~/.ssh/$keyfile
  done
  )
}
```